# Telerik-MVC Grid Display value of property versus edit value

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-3, telerik, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

Hopefully this will have a simple answer.

Using MVC3, I am passing a simple list of POCO objects as a model to my view:

```
public partial class PeopleAddress
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    public string Address2 { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string Zip { get; set; }
    public int PersonId { get; set; }

    public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
}
```

I use the PeopleId as the FK property to the Person entity, and the Person navigational property to navigate to the object. Here is my controller for the view:

```
public ViewResult Index()
    {
        var peopleaddresses = db.PeopleAddresses.Include("Person");
        return View(peopleaddresses.ToList());
    }
```

Pretty trivial. I add the columns to the grid and normal edit modes, etc in the view, but for the PersonId property.

**QUESTION ABOUT COLUMNS: How can I get the select (normal) mode to display the model.Person.Name, but keep the edit mode on editing model.PersonId? For model binding purposes, I need the HTTP post to send PersonId.**

Help!

Answer (score 0):

## Simple

If all you need is the Person.Id when you hit edit (you're editing outside the grid or something), then it IS that simple.  Your column would be:

```
columns.Bound(e => e.Person).Title("Person").ClientTemplate("<#= Person ? Person.Name : '' #>");
```

And you can get the Id for the person:

```
onEdit(e) {
    var personId = e.dataItem['Person'].Id;
}
```

## Full

However, if you're trying to edit in the grid using a combobox, your column should look like:

```
columns.Bound(e => e.Person).Title("Person").ClientTemplate("<#= Person ? Person.Name : '' #>").EditorTemplateName("PersonSelector");
```

your editor template:

```
@(Html.Telerik().ComboBox()
.Name("YourNameGoesHere")
.DataBinding(binding => binding.Ajax().Select("SelectPeopleForComboBox","Shared")))
```

Your client script:

```
onEdit(e){
    $comboBox = $(e.cell).find('#Person');
    if($comboBox.length > 0) {
        var comboBox = $ddl.data('tComboBox');
        comboBox.fill(function(){
            if (e.dataItem['Person'] != null){
                    ddl.value(e.dataItem['Person'].Id)
            }
        });
     }
}
```